# Swift 2.2 Generics: "Cannot convert return expression of type ItemPageControllerFactory to return type T"

Tags: ios, swift, generics, protocols, factory

I have an 'ItemContainer' protocol and UIViewController subclass 'ItemPageController' that conforms to the protocol.

I also have a 'ItemContainerControllerFactory' protocol and a struct that conforms to this protocol.

The issue: I wish to create a method that returns an appropriate ItemControllerControllerFactory sub-type. However, I get the following compiler error: **"Cannot convert return expression of type ItemPageControllerFactory to return type T"**

```
protocol ItemContainer {
    func navigateToItem(item:Item)
}

class ItemPageController : UIViewController, ItemContainer {
    func navigateToItem(item:Item) { ... }
}

protocol ItemContainerControllerFactory {
    associatedtype ContainerType : UIViewController, ItemContainer
    func itemContainerController() -> ContainerType
}

struct ItemPageControllerFactory: ItemContainerControllerFactory {
    typealias ContainerType = ItemPageController

    func itemContainerController() -> ContainerType {
        return ContainerType()
    }
}

//Goal: Be able to return different ItemContainerControllerFactory depending on some logic... (Currently hard coded to ItemPageControllerFactory)
func itemContainerFactory<T:ItemContainerControllerFactory>() -> T {    
    return ItemPageControllerFactory() //COMPILER ERROR: "Cannot convert return expression of type ItemPageControllerFactory to return type T"
}
```

Any ideas of what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: change `return ItemPageControllerFactory()` to `return T()`

Comment: Why are you using a generic there? The return value is of a constant type. The reason Swift is complaining is that the caller of the function has no idea what it returns, as it never inputs anything into it in order for the type of `T` to be inferred.

Comment: 1) If I get it working it won't be hard coded (I want to be able to return different ItemContainerControllerFactory types)


2) I thought that T would be bound to the return type (ItemPageControllerFactory) and thus the caller would be able to infer the type?

Comment: The caller defines the type of the generic, not the function. If you want to use different kinds of sub-types, you will have to identify them by a related parent type. In this case, ItemContainerControllerFactory

Answer (score 1):

In order to create a generic instance with protocols as you are, you need an initializer in your protocol

something like this:

```
protocol TestProtocol {
    init()
}

func create<T: TestProtocol>() -> T {
    return T()
}
```

Comment: It's not quite what I'm after. I'd like the 'create' method in your example to decide which type (of valid TestProtocol subtypes) to return for me. The caller should only know about the 'TestProtocol' interface.

Comment: That's not what your error was, so I fixed that :-) If that's indeed what you're doing, you don't need to use generics.

Comment: Is it possible to describe the following type without generics? "associatedtype ContainerType : UIViewController, ItemContainer " (like UIViewController<ContainerType> in Objective-C)